# How to set default value while using env in elasticsearch.yml config file?

Tags: elasticsearch, configuration, environment-variables, elastic-stack

I'm using environment variable in the config file (ie. elasticsearch.yml) to configure node roles.

For example:

**elasticsearch.yml:**

```yaml
node.roles: '${NODE_ROLES}'
```

When, I set `NODE_ROLES="master"`, `NODE_ROLES="ml, remote_cluster_client"`, etc. They work as expected.

But, When I try to create a **coordinating** node by setting, `NODE_ROLES=""`, seems like it doesn't work. Showing all node roles are assigned to coordinating nodes.

```sh
$ curl -XGET -k -u 'elastic:XpBr*PVVgPa&zK5M' "https://localhost:9200/_cat/nodes?v"
ip        heap.percent ram.percent cpu load_1m load_5m load_15m node.role   master name
10.2.2.23           59          74  42    2.40    1.83     1.23 m           -      es-master-0
... ... ..
10.2.0.18           69           2  19    0.78    0.48     0.33 cdfhilmrstw -      es-coordinating-0
```

I also tried setting default values like below, they also didn't work.

```yaml
node.roles: '${NODE_ROLES:""}'
or 
node.roles: '${NODE_ROLES:[]}'
```

Comment: We basically have the same issue with the difference that we run ES via `docker run ... -e node.roles=<WTF to define here for a coordinating only node?!?> ...`. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @GeroldBroser Nope! Maybe they will update their environment parser one day.

Comment: @GeroldBroser And please let me know if you figure out the solution.

Comment: There's the same question at https://discuss.elastic.co/t/problem-with-node-roles-on-latest-elasticsearch-docker-7-11-0/264359 ... with no answer, and closed.

Comment: And there's a new question now: [How to set node.roles for a coordinating only node via environment variable?](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-set-node-roles-for-a-coordinating-only-node-via-environment-variable/307860?u=gerib)

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

```
node.roles: []
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-node.html#coordinating-node

Or you can manually disable each role by name.

```
node.data: false
node.ingest: false
node.master: false 
// etc..
```

**node.role, r, role, nodeRole**
(Default) Roles of the node. Returned values include c (cold node), d (data node), f (frozen node), h (hot node), i (ingest node), l (machine learning node), m (master-eligible node), r (remote cluster client node), s (content node), t (transform node), v (voting-only node), w (warm node), and - (coordinating node only).

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-nodes.html

Comment: `node.data: true/false` has been deprecated and not supported in version > 7.13.

Comment: I need to configure `node.roles: []` via ENV. Please let me know, how can I achieve it.